# Simplify Javascript code with multiple logical operator in a filter function

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

can someone tell me how to simplify this code?

I have to edit this. I made a mistake.

Correction:

```
    this._test = test?.filter(({ foo }: Foo) => {
        return foo.isTrue(foo.a)
            || foo.isTrue(foo.b)
            || foo.isTrue(foo.c)
            || foo.isSuperTrue(foo.d)
            || foo.isSuperTrue(foo.e)
            || foo.isSuperTrue(foo.f)
    }).slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: do you have only properties a - f ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at `Array.prototype.some` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

You can change that return into something like this.

```js
return [ foo.a, foo.b, foo.c, foo.d, foo.e, foo.f ].some(foo.isTrue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some()`:

```js
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'].some(p => foo.isTrue(foo[p]))
```